# Making multiple objects with the same shader fade at different times

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, mesh

I have a death transformation for one of my GameObjects which goes from a spherical ball to a bunch of small individual blocks.  Each of these blocks I want to fade at different times but since they all use the same shader I cannot seem to figure out how to make all of them not fade out at the same time.

This first picture is the Spherical Ball in its first step for when it turns from a spherical ball to a Minecraft'ish looking block ball and to the right of it is one of the blocks that make up the Minecraft'ish looking ball shown by the red arrow.
[image]

Now this is my Inspector for one of the little blocks that make up the Minecraft'ish looking ball.
[image]

I have an arrow pointing to what makes the object fade but that is globally across all of the blocks since they use the same shader.  Is it possible to have each block fade separately or am I stuck and need to find a new disappear act for the little block dudes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the material property by script at runtime, and you need to do it through the `Renderer.material` property. When you access `Renderer.material`, Unity will automatically create a copy of the material for you that is handled separately -- including getting its own draw call, if you care about performance. You can tell this has happened because the material name in the renderer will change to "Materialname (Instance)".

Set the material's fade property using `Renderer.material.SetFloat()` (or whatever the appropriate `Set...` function is). Unfortunately the property's name isn't "Fade Factor". You can find the property's name by looking at the shader script, or by switching the inspector to debug mode and digging through the Saved Properties array for one that looks right.

Comment: Sounds good Gabriel I will give it a shot.  Thank you for the quick response too.

Comment: Works like a charm Gabriel Sibley.  Thank you very much for your help.